# is there a way to calculate birthyear, form age which is in years and current day and month is same birth day and month

Tags: java-8, controller, date

If I have the age of a person, and the current day and month are the same as the birthdate, how can I calculate the birthyear with Java 8?

For example:

- Age = 30 years
- Current date = July 1st, 2019
- Expected output = July 1st, 1989

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. This is not a coding service website. Show us, what you have done so far in a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and you'll get help

Comment: `LocalDate.now(yourZoneId).minusYears(30)`. [Tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Comment: As the others already hinted: Showing an effort on your part will make a lot of people here much more willing to do an effort to help you. You were trying in Java 8, great. Show us what, and how it failed.

Comment: On the page [Subtract years from date](https://www.leveluplunch.com/java/examples/subtract-years-from-date/) scroll down to *Java 8 Date and Time API*. It wasn’t too hard to find it using my search engine. I can’t help thinking that you may benefit from exercising yours more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## tl;dr

In other words, you want to subtract a number of years from a date.

```
LocalDate
.of( 2019 , Month.JULY , 1 ) 
.minusYears( 30 )
```

See this [code run live at IdeOne.com](https://ideone.com/mJ00YW).

> 1989-07-01

### `LocalDate`

The [`LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/LocalDate.html) class represents a date-only value without time-of-day and without [time zone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_zone) or [offset-from-UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTC_offset).

A time zone is crucial in determining a date. For any given moment, the date varies around the globe by zone. For example, a few minutes after midnight in [Paris France](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Europe/Paris) is a new day while still “yesterday” in [Montréal Québec](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/America/Montreal).

If no time zone is specified, the JVM implicitly applies its current default time zone. That default may [change at any moment](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/TimeZone.html#setDefault(java.util.TimeZone)) during runtime(!), so your results may vary. Better to specify your desired/expected time zone explicitly as an argument. If critical, confirm the zone with your user.

Specify a [proper time zone name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_zones_by_name) in the format of `Continent/Region`, such as `America/Montreal`, `Africa/Casablanca`, or `Pacific/Auckland`. Never use the 2-4 letter abbreviation such as `EST` or `IST` as they are *not* true time zones, not standardized, and not even unique(!).

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" ) ;  
LocalDate today = LocalDate.now( z ) ;
```

If you want to use the JVM’s current default time zone, ask for it and pass as an argument. If omitted, the code becomes ambiguous to read in that we do not know for certain if you intended to use the default or if you, like so many programmers, were unaware of the issue.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.systemDefault() ;  // Get JVM’s current default time zone.
```

Or specify a date. You may set the month by a number, with sane numbering 1-12 for January-December.

```
LocalDate ld = LocalDate.of( 1986 , 2 , 23 ) ;  // Years use sane direct numbering (1986 means year 1986). Months use sane numbering, 1-12 for January-December.
```

Or, better, use the [`Month`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Month.html) enum objects pre-defined, one for each month of the year. Tip: Use these `Month` objects throughout your codebase rather than a mere integer number to make your code more self-documenting, ensure valid values, and provide [type-safety](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_safety). Ditto for [`Year`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Year.html) & [`YearMonth`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/YearMonth.html).

```
LocalDate ld = LocalDate.of( 1986 , Month.FEBRUARY , 23 ) ;
```

## `MonthDay`

I have a hunch what you really need is [`MonthDay`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/MonthDay.html) to represent the idea of an annual birthday, just the month and the day-of-month but without a year.

From a `MonthDay` object you can determine a date for any year, generating a `LocalDate` object. Use [`Year`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Year.html) class to get current year.

```
MonthDay birthMonthDay = MonthDay.of( Month.JANUARY , 23 ) ;
LocalDate birthDateSomeYear = birthMonthDay.atYear( 2010 ) ;
LocalDate birthDateThisYear = birthMonthDay.atYear( Year.now( z ).getValue() ) ;
```

A month-day of February 29th will be adjusted to February 28th in a non-leap year.

## Date math

You can subtract a number of years from a `LocalDate`, producing a new `LocalDate` object.

```
int ageInYears = 37 ;
LocalDate then = someLocalDate.minusYears( ageInYears ) ;
```

If you meant you have the age in a finer resolution of years-months-days, use [`Period`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Period.html) class.

```
Period p = Period.of( 37 , 4 , 2 ) ; // years-months-days.
```

Do the math.

```
LocalDate ld = someLocalDate.minus( p ) ;
```

Answer (score 0):

I am beginner for Java, so asked. but I got solution. Thank you guys for suggestion.

```
public class test {

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            int age = 30;
            Date today = new Date();
            Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
            cal.setTime(today);

            int dayOfYear = cal.get(Calendar.YEAR);
            int birthYear = dayOfYear - age;
            System.out.println(birthYear);
            // using local time
            LocalDate todayDate = LocalDate.now();
            int y = todayDate.getYear();
            int birthYearFromTime = y-age;
            System.out.println(birthYearFromTime);

        }

}
```

Comment: Thank you for sharing your own two solutions. The latter one is the one to go with. The classes `Date` and `Calendar` are poorly designed and long outdated, so don’t use those.